Argo workflows template: using variable for name in valueFrom
So I try to get the value from a configMap as input to a template in a Argo workflow template. I want to use a variable in the name attribute, see example.
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: configmapkeyref-variable-name
spec:
  entrypoint: prepare
  ttlStrategy:
    secondsAfterCompletion: 3600 # 1h
  podGC:
    strategy: OnWorkflowSuccess
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: system
        value: a
  templates:
    - name: prepare
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: system
            value: '{{workflow.parameters.system}}'
          - name: hook
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: "hooks-{{workflow.parameters.system}}" # This don't work!
                # name: "hooks-a" # This works!
                key: prepare
              default: "default value"
      script:
        image: ubuntu:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        source: |
          echo "system: {{workflow.parameters.system}}"
          echo "system: {{inputs.parameters.system}}"
          echo "HOOK: {{inputs.parameters.hook}}"

I'm not sure it this is possible at all but need to get fetch different configMap depending on the value of parameter "system".
I  wonder if anyone can help me out with this? =) I have spent a lot of time to read on the documentation pages but i'm stuck :/
Best regards
Thomas

I adjusted my example using an env var instead of an input which work as I wanted to.
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: configmapkeyref-variable-name
spec:
  entrypoint: prepare
  ttlStrategy:
    secondsAfterCompletion: 3600 # 1h
  podGC:
    strategy: OnWorkflowSuccess
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: system
        value: adam
  templates:
    - name: prepare
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: system
            value: '{{workflow.parameters.system}}'
      script:
        image: ubuntu:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        env:
          - name: HOOK
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: "hooks-{{inputs.parameters.system}}"
                key: prepare
                optional: true
        source: |
          echo "system: {{workflow.parameters.system}}"
          echo "system: {{inputs.parameters.system}}"
          echo "HOOK: $HOOK"

This works for me and I don't know why I can't use a variable in the "name" attribute of the ConfigMapKeyRef when it is used in the "input" section but works in the "env" section, could be by design or a bug.
